# Spring annotations for factory method

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring 3.0 for my project, I am having a class MySingletonClass, it is singleton as below :

```
//@Component("mySingletonClass")
public class MySingletonClass {
    private static MySingletonClass obj = new MySingletonClass();

    public static MySingletonClass getSingleObj() {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

spring xml bean configuration for this class is as below :

```
<bean id="mySingletonClass" class="app.MySingletonClass"  factory-method="getSingleObj" />
```

I was trying to remove bean configuration and use annotation. how do I write annotation for factory method?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/9598829/184536

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring creates instances like singleton by default. You can just do.

```
    @Component("mySingletonClass")
    public class MySingletonClass {
    }
```

And if you don't change scope your component is singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Spring component's are automatically created as Singletons.

Declare the annotation @Controller on the class

```
@Controller
public class MySingletonClass {
}
```

Then in your Spring Config file, declare like:

`<bean id="mySingleton" class="com.package.MySingletonClass">`

Then to use in another class you can use Autowiring or Setter/Constructor dependency injection.

```
@Component 
public class OtherClass {
    @Autowired
    private MySingletonClass mySingleton;
}
```