# annotation based factory methods

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I want to be able to autowire a singleton bean (`foo`)

```
@Component
public class FooUser {

  @Autowire Foo foo;
}
```

created by another singleton's method (`FooFactory.createFoo`)

```
@Service
public class FooFactory {

  public Foo createFoo() {...}
}
```

with xml it's simply `factory-method`. How can i do it with annotation?

Comment: I don't think you can.  I think Spring is only able to autowire beans it manages.  But if you have a factory class/method, why not just call that to get your bean?

Comment: Perhaps this question is relevant?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598829/spring-3-component-and-static-factory-method?rq=1

Comment: @Marvo: i can make this bean managed by spring. by i don't know how. i can create 1 more singleton (MiddleManService) and use it to call factory and later everywhere do `@Autowire MiddleManService middleMan` and later `middleMan.getFoo()`. but why? i want it sipler. i want just `@Autwired Foo foo`. it's simple with xml. how about annotations?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try Java `@Configuration` instead:

```
@Configuration 
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public FooUser fooUser() {
        return new FooUser(foo());
    }

    @Bean
    public FooFactory fooFactory() {
        return new FooFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return fooFactory().createFoo();
    }

}
```

Comment: That's fine, and how to define if you want that as a singleton?

Comment: You don't have to do this. Because bean scope is singleton by default in spring.

Comment: I wouldn't do that.
Don't call methods directly but use injection by parameter.
otherwise: `fooUser().getFoo() != AppContext.getBean(Foo.class)`
Because you have called the method manually, before it was singletoned by spring

Answer (score 4):

You need java-config - [the `@Bean` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html).

Define your class as `@Configuration` and your method as `@Bean`

Answer (score 4):

Spring Components can also define factory methods. A snipped from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factorybeans-annotations):

```
@Component
public class FactoryMethodComponent {

  @Bean @Qualifier("public")
  public TestBean publicInstance() {
      return new TestBean("publicInstance");
  }

  public void doWork() {
      // Component method implementation omitted
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the FactoryBean Spring interface. then u will be able to autowire T itself

---

EDIT:
The BeanFactory is an interface in Spring where if you implement it You can make a factory of the  object such as :

```
public class FooFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Foo>{
   .................. 
   }
```

then you can initialize the bean :

```
@Bean
public FooFactoryBean foo(){ 
      return new FooFactoryBean(); 
    }
```

then if you autowired Foo it Spring will understand the FooFactoryBean is the desired factory

```
   @Autowired
       Foo foo;
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense to me. There is no T mentioned in the question.

Comment: the  BeanFactory<T>  is an interface in Spring where I you implement it you can make a factory of the <T> object such as :
      public class FooFactoryBean implements  FactoryBean<Foo>{
       ..................
           }
then you can initialize the bean :
        public FooFactoryBean foo(){ return new FooFactoryBean(); }
then if you autowired Foo it Spring will understand the FooFactoryBean is the desired factory

Comment: I have this pattern, but I am getting 6 different instances of my singleton beans. Yes, I have multiple contexts - Application context, job context, web context, etc. There needs to be a clean way to reliably get a singleton bean.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot: factory method

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

enum ParsersConst {
    bofa, jpm, wellsforgo
}

interface Parser {
    String readFromFile(String file);
}

class JPM implements Parser {
    @Override
    public String readFromFile(String file) {
        System.out.println("From JPM Parser");
        //LOGIC to read file data
        return "JPM";
    }
}

class Bofa implements Parser {
    @Override
    public String readFromFile(String file) {
        System.out.println("From Bofa Parser");
        //LOGIC to read file data
        return "BOFA";
    }
}

class WellsForgo implements Parser {
    @Override
    public String readFromFile(String file) {
        System.out.println("From Wellsforgo Parser"); 
        //LOGIC to read file data
        return "WellsForgo";
    }
}

class ParserCreator {
    private Map<ParsersConst, Parser> parserMap;

    public Parser createParser(ParsersConst parsConst) {
        Parser parser = parserMap.get(parsConst);
        if (parserMap.get(parsConst) != null) {
            return parser;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Parser");
    }

    public void setParserMap(Map<ParsersConst, Parser> parserMap) {
        this.parserMap = parserMap;
    }
}

@Configuration
class ParserConfig {

    @Bean
    public ParserCreator parserCreatorFactory() {
        ParserCreator factory = new ParserCreator();
        Map<ParsersConst, Parser> map = new HashMap<ParsersConst, Parser>();
        map.put(ParsersConst.bofa, new Bofa());
        map.put(ParsersConst.wellsforgo, new WellsForgo());
        map.put(ParsersConst.jpm, new JPM());
        factory.setParserMap(map);
        return factory;

    }

    @Bean
    public Parser bofa() {
        return parserCreatorFactory().createParser(ParsersConst.bofa);
    }

    @Bean
    public Parser wellsforgo() {
        return parserCreatorFactory().createParser(ParsersConst.wellsforgo);
    }

    @Bean
    public Parser jpm() {
        return parserCreatorFactory().createParser(ParsersConst.jpm);
    }
}

@Component
public class StaticFacotryDemo implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Parser parser = (Parser) context.getBean(ParsersConst.jpm.toString());
        System.out.println(parser.readFromFile("jan_stmt.pdf"));

    }

}
```