# Spring dependency autowiring and private methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Using Spring annotations to autowire dependencies, I'm getting a `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` because I have a class with a private constructor and a public static get-method, both of which return instances of the class.

That class is annotated with the `@Service` annotation, and the static get method is annotated with `@Bean`.

I know that I can use the `@Qualifier` annotation at the injection point to disambiguate, and if I just remove the @Bean annotation, Spring uses the constructor without issue.

But I'd prefer Spring to use the static method -- maybe the method does some setup (Yes, I know that Spring beans are by default singleton -- still, maybe I have a reason to want to force all construction to go through my method, rather than directly to my constructor.)

1. Is there a way to tell Spring, as a general policy, to prefer public methods to non-public ones (in this case, the private constructor) when satisfying dependencies?

Or, less appealingly,

1. Is there a way (some annotation) to explicitly exclude the constructor in the `@Service` class from Spring's consideration?

Comment: Please show us a short example and the full stacktrace. I feel like I'm misunderstanding your setup.

Comment: Have you tried this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779994/annotation-based-factory-methods

Comment: Also state the Spring version you are using.